# How do I use the within transformation for logistic regression?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, estimation, econometrics

I would like to estimate a logistic regression model where the target variable $y_{it}$ is grouped. It is the number of experiments and the number of successes for a given unit $i$ during time period $t$. I would like to fit a fixed effects model and additional covariates $X_{it}$. [This](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/246548/difference-between-one-way-and-two-way-fixed-effects-and-their-estimation) post presents the "within transformation" as a way to estimate OLS fixed effects models. In that case, the target $y_{it}$ is continuous and the OLS model is transformed as:

$$y_{it} - \bar y_i - \bar y_t + \bar y_{it} = (\bf x_{it} - \bar x_i - \bar x_t + \bar x_{it})\bf \beta$$

I don't see how this can be used in logistic regression since $y_{it}$ is not a single number but 2 related counts. Is there any way to approach this other than the dummy variable method?

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by the "within transformation"?

Comment: Updated with details.

Comment: Although the question was already answered to your satisfaction, out of curiosity: why don't you directly fit a logistic regression with the grouped data? This is a bit tricky in R (use proportions as response and the number of experiments in `weights`), but it is built into `glm`.

Comment: I have a model with group fixed effects and hundreds of other variables I want to regularize. I tried to fit it with `glmnet`, using a $0$ penalty for the fixed effects, but `glmnet` runs into numerical issues and doesn't converge. So I am looking at different approaches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The within transformation will not work because of the non-linearity of the logit function. There are some possible solutions:

1. Fit a panel linear probability FE model
2. Conditional logit
3. Unconditional fixed effects logit estimator using dummies
4. [Pseudo-demeaning algorithm](https://www.econstor.eu/handle/10419/145837)
5. [CRE](https://conference.iza.org/conference_files/SUMS_2013/slides_2_nonlin_iza.pdf) (Mundlak-Chamberlain device)