# How do I analyse the impact of various macroeconomic factors on 7 currency pairs?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, multivariate-analysis, descriptive-statistics, macroeconomics

I’m doing a Bachelor Thesis on “The Impact of Macroeconomic Factors On Currency Exchange Rates”. Narrowing down towards my methodology section, my professor advised me to analyse about 7 currency pairs to help get a good conclusion on the thesis topic. I want to know how I can do it to find how select macroeconomic factors would impact those 7 currency pairs individually? Will a multivariate regression analysis work in this case? Or else do I have to analyse each currency pair (dependent variable) separately?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Treating this as panel data and using a two-way fixed effects (FX pair specific and time specific) could be a way forward. See e.g. [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/246548/difference-between-one-way-and-two-way-fixed-effects-and-their-estimation).